# Best practice to upload 2tb from local hard disk to s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We want to upload 2TB of data from our local hard disk to the S3 bucket. So what will be the best practice to do it faster and cheaper? What will be the estimated cost and time to upload data as well as per month storage cost as it will be less frequently accessed?

Comment: What's the cost of electricity? time and amount of equipment used? will you include the lighting and heating / cooling costs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are reasonably technical, you can use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). It has an [`aws s3 sync` command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) that can copy a directory (including subdirectories) to/from Amazon S3. It only copies new/changed files so if anything goes wrong you can re-run the command. It copies files in parallel to take advantage of your available bandwidth.

A more **user-friendly option** is to use a utility that knows how to communicate with S3, such as [Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io/).

If you need a more demanding solution, consider [AWS DataSync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datasync/latest/userguide/what-is-datasync.html) -- *"AWS DataSync is an online data movement and discovery service that simplifies data migration and helps you quickly, easily, and securely move your file or object data to, from, and between AWS storage services."*

The **speed of upload** will totally depend on the speed and quality of *your* Internet connection.

**Costs** associated with Amazon S3 can be found at: [Amazon S3 Simple Storage Service Pricing - Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/)

Costs can be reduced in s3 by choosing an appropriate [Object Storage Class – Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/storage-classes/). Less-frequently accessed files can be stored in cheaper storage classes, but there is an additional cost when accessing the data.

Comment: what about https://aws.amazon.com/s3/transfer-acceleration/ ?

Comment: @dev Yes, Transfer Acceleration can help if the users are a long distance from the Region. First, utilize the full bandwidth, then try to reduce the latency.

Comment: ok , what do you mean by " First, utilize the full bandwidth, then try to reduce the latency "  i did not get it ?

Comment: Using the AWS CLI or DataSync will more fully use the available bandwidth by uploading files in parallel. It gives the biggest gain. If even more performance is required, then consider S3 Transfer Acceleration to reduce the latency since traffic to the Region will flow over the AWS network. Think of it like a bus -- to transport a large number of people, first put many people in each bus. If that's not enough, then drive the bus on a tollway that has faster traffic. But driving a bus on a tollway with only one passenger won't improve the 'people throughput' very much.